# Python Add Label to Each Point in Polar Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following sample dataset:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

# Angle In Radians
theta = [i/180*np.pi for i in  [0,90,180,270]]
# Radius
radius = [1,2,3,4]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.scatter(theta,radius, c ='r')
ax.set_title("Graph Title here", va='bottom')
pyplot.show()
```

This outputs the following plot:

[image]

Now my question is: Is it possible to add a label next to each point which tells me the angle and radius of that plot?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` and round off your angles to 2 decimal places as following

```
for t, r in zip(theta, radius):
    ax.annotate("{:.2f},{}".format(t, r), xy=[t, r], fontsize=16)

pyplot.show()
```

If you want angles in degrees, you can use

```
for t, r in zip(theta, radius):
    ax.annotate("{},{}".format(int(t*180/np.pi), r), xy=[t, r], fontsize=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! ... and wow that was fast! I could just convert the angle back to degree, then  I don't have to round (for this specific case).

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: What if the theta is also the radius? For example if the polar plot represents wind direction, where each point is placed based on direction (in degrees) the winds blows to.